# How can I solve the error that I get when compiling my mobile app in flutter?

Tags: api, rest, flutter, flutter-test

*This is the error I get when compiling*

**An Observatory debugger and profiler on AOSP on IA Emulator is available at: http://127.0.0.1:55598/YYOpp337z7w=/
E/flutter (19984): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The method 'toDouble' was called on null.
E/flutter (19984): Receiver: null
E/flutter (19984): Tried calling: toDouble()**

***This is the class where I make the request to the REST API***

```
class HttpHandler{

final String  _baseUrl = "api.themoviedb.org";
  final String _lenguaje = "es-ES";

Future<dynamic> getJson(Uri uri) async{
      //Primera peticion api  
    http.Response response = await http.get(uri); //amacena la respuesta
    return json.decode(response.body);

    }

    Future<List<Media>> fetchMovies(){
      //define la la url
      var uri = new Uri.https(_baseUrl, "3/movie/popular",{
        'api_key' : API_KEY,
        'page': "1",
        'language ': _lenguaje
      });

      return getJson(uri).then(((data) =>
          data['results'].map<Media>((item)=>new Media(item)).toList()
      ));
    }
```

***My constructor method based on the design of the object that the API request sends me***

```
class Media {

  int id;
  double voteAverage;
  String title;
  String posterPath;
  String  backdropPath;
  String overview;
  String releaseDate;
  List<dynamic> genreIds;

  String getPosterUrl() => getMediumPictureUrl(posterPath);

//Definir el constructor
//Basado de diseño de factory en la base de disñeo de objetos
factory Media(Map jsonMap){
    try {
       return new Media.deserialize(jsonMap);
    } catch (ex) {

      throw ex;
     }

     }

    Media.deserialize(Map json) :
    id = json["id"].toInt(),
    voteAverage = json["voteAverage"].toDouble(),
    title = json["title"],
    posterPath = json["posterPath"]?? "",
    backdropPath = json["backdropPath"]?? "",
    overview =  json["overview"],
    releaseDate = json["releaseDate"],
    genreIds = json["genreIds"].toList;


}
```

***This is the flutter view where the request is called to show in this case a list of movies***

```
class MediaList extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MediaListState createState() => new _MediaListState();
 }
class _MediaListState extends State<MediaList> {
List<Media> _media = new List();
  @override
  void initState(){
    super.initState();
    loadMovies();
  }
  void loadMovies()async{
    var movies = await HttpHandler().fetchMovies();
    setState(() {
      _media.addAll(movies);
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return new Container(
     child: new ListView.builder(
       itemCount: _media.length,
       itemBuilder: (BuildContext context ,int index){
          return new Column(
            children: <Widget>[
                new Image.network(_media[index].getPosterUrl())
            ],
          );
       },
     ),

   );
  }
}
```

Comment: voteAverage = json["voteAverage"].toDouble(),   replace this with  voteAverage = (json["voteAverage"]==null)?' ':json["voteAverage"].toDouble();

Answer (score 0):

Add a null check on your `voteAverage = json["voteAverage"].toDouble(),`

The updated code will look like `voteAverage = json["voteAverage"]?.toDouble(),`

Hope this solves your problem!

Answer (score 0):

The json["voteAverage"] object is of null value and therefor the operation can't be performed. Check if the json object exists at all and check if the voteAverage is present. If that isn't the case, the url is most likely wrong or you are not awaiting the response.